# Codenameone:Send Log Error comes when internet is down

Tags: codenameone

Sometimes when my internet is down, I get the following log error:

```
Device not Registered : Sending a log from an unregistered device is impossible
```

Why does this error happen? What does it mean?

Comment: Do you have a pro account?

Comment: No. I have basic account

Comment: we don't want that pop-up to come on screen

Comment: Send log error is a pro feature

Comment: I don't want that pop-up so what should I do for that

Comment: What popup? send log is a pro feature there is no popup

Comment: Sending a log from an unregistered device is impossible    this message popup comes on screen...i dont want this message popup to come on screen

Comment: Don't call `sendLog` and you won't get that message...

Comment: I see this message with pro account as well. is there any reason for this?